# What is the name of this post-apocalyptic setting?

Tags: product-identification, post-apocalyptic

There is a post-apocalyptic setting that I've always wanted to play/GM and finally found a group for but I can not find the system anymore.

Here is what I remember:

- Post-Apocalyptic
- Scene Based
- Free online PDF
- Modern and slightly beyond tech but more about salvage then inventing.
- I think they used slightly modified stats, 4 core stats with one begin
  something like "Gutz"
- Low magic. Whatever caused the apocalyptic caused a rift that allowed magic. But mostly it was like mind reading psychic type with some healing ect.
- Many classes revolved around access to items/equipment that would be rare. Medic might have a small makeshift lab. Mechanic might have a small workshop with some tools.  Occult leader would have their followers and maybe a base. Mob leader might have a base. Bike gang leader might have a small group of NPC bikers.

Comment: Yup, @InterstellarProbe. Do please up that up as an answer instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like [Apocalypse World](http://apocalypse-world.com)! It's not a setting but a complete game.

Apocalypse World 2nd Edition is the latest edition, but it's not free. However, the earlier 1st Edition is available as a free download at http://apocalypse-world.com.

- Stats are Cool, Hard, Hot, Sharp, Weird, and Hx (history).
- Your class descriptions sound like the [playbooks](http://apocalypse-world.com/ApocalypseWorldBasicRefbook2ndEd.pdf) for The Angel, The Savvyhead, The  Hocus, The Hardholder, and The Chopper.

Comment: The first edition is available for free at apocalypse-world.com and is probably what they experienced if this happened long enough ago to be forgotten.

Comment: @Glazius Great, I updated my answer.

Comment: You might also want to note that the printouts required for the game --- character sheets, move lists and such, are also available for free for 2e, which might be enough for those already familiar with how the game works.